# Listing missing months in an array of dates

Tags: ruby, arrays, date, methods

I have a list of transactions in an array.

```
=> [Wed, 23 Oct 2013, Mon, 18 Nov 2013, Fri, 22 Nov 2013, Mon, 13 Jan 2014, Tue, 28 Jan 2014, Mon, 03 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Tue, 18 Feb 2014, Fri, 07 Mar 2014, Mon, 31 Mar 2014, Mon, 07 Apr 2014, Tue, 10 Jun 2014, Mon, 30 Jun 2014, Mon, 22 Sep 2014, Mon, 06 Oct 2014, Fri, 14 Nov 2014, Tue, 18 Nov 2014, Fri, 26 Dec 2014, Thu, 15 Jan 2015, Mon, 23 Mar 2015, Mon, 20 Apr 2015]
```

I need to compare the dates of each transaction and list any months that are missing in the list of months and year. Here is what I have now...

```
@find_transactions = (@user.transactions.find_all { |t| (t.name 'name' })
@trans_dates = @find_transactions.map(&:date).sort!.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%Y-%m') }.each_cons(2).map{ |d1,d2| d1.next_month == d2 }
```

This method currently gives me a true or false if each month is there but I need to actually have the method print a list of months that are missing. I would like to have it print the month and year together.

Here is the response this method gives me...

```
=> [true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true]
```

I want a response like this...

```
=> [March 2015, December 2014, September 2014]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: For array already being composed of date objects you can do:*

```
require 'date'

dates = [Wed, 23 Oct 2013, Mon, 18 Nov 2013, Fri, 22 Nov 2013, Mon, 13 Jan 2014, Tue, 28 Jan 2014, Mon, 03 Feb 2014, Mon, 10 Feb 2014, Tue, 18 Feb 2014, Fri, 07 Mar 2014, Mon, 31 Mar 2014, Mon, 07 Apr 2014, Tue, 10 Jun 2014, Mon, 30 Jun 2014, Mon, 22 Sep 2014, Mon, 06 Oct 2014, Fri, 14 Nov 2014, Tue, 18 Nov 2014, Fri, 26 Dec 2014, Thu, 15 Jan 2015, Mon, 23 Mar 2015, Mon, 20 Apr 2015]

all_dates = []
dates.first.upto(dates.last) {|x| all_dates << x.strftime('%b %Y') if x.day == 1 || x == dates.first}

d = dates.map {|x| x.strftime('%b %Y')}.uniq

p (all_dates - d)
  #=> ["Dec 2013", "May 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Feb 2015"]
```

---

*Edit: Below methods are for an array of date strings*

You can try this:

```
require 'date'

dates = ["Wed, 23 Oct 2013", "Mon, 18 Nov 2013", "Fri, 22 Nov 2013", "Mon, 13 Jan 2014", "Tue, 28 Jan 2014", "Mon, 03 Feb 2014", "Mon, 10 Feb 2014", "Tue, 18 Feb 2014", "Fri, 07 Mar 2014", "Mon, 31 Mar 2014", "Mon, 07 Apr 2014", "Tue, 10 Jun 2014", "Mon, 30 Jun 2014", "Mon, 22 Sep 2014", "Mon, 06 Oct 2014", "Fri, 14 Nov 2014", "Tue, 18 Nov 2014", "Fri, 26 Dec 2014", "Thu, 15 Jan 2015", "Mon, 23 Mar 2015", "Mon, 20 Apr 2015"]

all_dates = []
d = dates.map {|x| Date.parse(x[8..-1])}.uniq
counter = d.first

until counter == d.last
  all_dates << counter
  counter = counter.next_month
end


p (all_dates - d).map {|x| x.strftime('%b %Y')}
  #=> ["Dec 2013", "May 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Feb 2015"]
```

---

Another (more concise) way would be:

```
require 'date'

dates = ["Wed, 23 Oct 2013", "Mon, 18 Nov 2013", "Fri, 22 Nov 2013", "Mon, 13 Jan 2014", "Tue, 28 Jan 2014", "Mon, 03 Feb 2014", "Mon, 10 Feb 2014", "Tue, 18 Feb 2014", "Fri, 07 Mar 2014", "Mon, 31 Mar 2014", "Mon, 07 Apr 2014", "Tue, 10 Jun 2014", "Mon, 30 Jun 2014", "Mon, 22 Sep 2014", "Mon, 06 Oct 2014", "Fri, 14 Nov 2014", "Tue, 18 Nov 2014", "Fri, 26 Dec 2014", "Thu, 15 Jan 2015", "Mon, 23 Mar 2015", "Mon, 20 Apr 2015"]

all_dates = []
d = dates.map {|x| Date.parse(x[8..-1])}.uniq

d.first.upto(d.last) {|x| all_dates << x if x.day == 1}

p (all_dates - d).map {|x| x.strftime('%b %Y')}
  #=> ["Dec 2013", "May 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Feb 2015"]
```

Comment: Good one, Sid. Clever use of `parse`. Egad, there's a `Date#next_month` method!. I wasted a lot of time rolling my own.  I see you can also write it using `Date@>>`, which looks rather cool.

Comment: Thanks Cary, I felt the same when I first found out about `Date#next_month` method!

Comment: Question does the 8..-1 represent the start month? Because the start month will be different times during the year.

Comment: @SupremeA [8..-1] gets the eighth to the last character for each date you have in your initial array so it returns just the month and year for each date. For example, for the first date in your array it will return "Oct 2013", for the second: "Nov 2013", for the third: "Nov 2013" etc.

Comment: @Sid I am getting the error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[ ]' for Tue, 01 Oct 2013:Date` when I get to the d= line it seems to be having trouble with the [8..-1] piece

Comment: @Sid could my issue be the fact that my dates array is not seperated by "" like the one in your example? Mine looks like this  `=> [Tue, 01 Oct 2013, Fri, 01 Nov 2013, Fri, 01 Nov 2013, Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Wed, 01 Jan 2014, Sat, 01 Feb 2014, Sat, 01 Feb 2014, Sat, 01 Feb 2014, Sat, 01 Mar 2014, Sat, 01 Mar 2014, Tue, 01 Apr 2014, Sun, 01 Jun 2014, Sun, 01 Jun 2014, Mon, 01 Sep 2014, Wed, 01 Oct 2014, Sat, 01 Nov 2014, Sat, 01 Nov 2014, Mon, 01 Dec 2014, Thu, 01 Jan 2015, Sun, 01 Mar 2015, Wed, 01 Apr 2015]`

Comment: @SupremeA ah that means your array has actual date objects not strings with dates as I and the other answerers assumed.

Comment: I'll update my answer in a few minutes when I'm at a computer

Comment: @SupremeA: I was wondering how you were able to have commas after the day name in all your dates above and no quotes but assumed you had manually typed your array. So, if you type `<array_name>[0].class` (fill in your array_name) the output is `Date`? As @Sid said, we all were working off the original array being full of `Strings`. (Edit: Your error message seems to imply the output will be `Date`.)

Comment: @pjd: The output is a copy and paste after I run the 1st and 2nd line of my original code. If you look at the 2nd line, that 2nd map converts the strings into date objects, this might not be completely right to do so many things in 1 line but I am quite new and I will refactor after everything works

Comment: @SupremeA can you post what `@find_transactions` is (that results in that array you gave)

Comment: @SupremeA left some code in that didn't need to be. Please try again!

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you could do that.

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def missing_months(dates)    
  a = dates.map { |s| d = Date.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y'); d - d.day + 1 }
  (all_months_in_range(*a.minmax) -a).map { |d| d.strftime('%b %Y') } 
end

def all_months_in_range(f,l)
  (12*(l.year-f.year)+l.month-f.month+1).times.map do |i|
    y,m = (f.month+i).divmod(12)
    y += f.year
    (m=12; y-=1) if m ==0
    Date.new(y,m)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
dates = ['Wed, 23 Oct 2013', 'Mon, 18 Nov 2013', 'Fri, 22 Nov 2013',
         'Fri, 14 Nov 2014', 'Tue, 18 Nov 2014', 'Fri, 26 Dec 2014',
         'Mon, 13 Jan 2014', 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014', 'Mon, 03 Feb 2014',
         'Mon, 31 Mar 2014', 'Mon, 07 Apr 2014', 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014',
         'Mon, 30 Jun 2014', 'Mon, 22 Sep 2014', 'Mon, 06 Oct 2014',
         'Mon, 10 Feb 2014', 'Tue, 18 Feb 2014', 'Fri, 07 Mar 2014',
         'Thu, 15 Jan 2015', 'Mon, 23 Mar 2015', 'Mon, 20 Apr 2015']

missing_months(dates)     
  #=> ["Dec 2013", "May 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Feb 2015"]
```

Notice that the `dates` needn't be sorted.

**Explanation**

For the example above:

```
  a = dates.map { |s| d = Date.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y'); d - d.day + 1 }
    #=> [#<Date: 2013-10-01 ((2456567j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2013-11-01 ((2456598j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #   ...
    #    #<Date: 2015-04-01 ((2457114j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Notice that each of these dates is on the first of the month. Next, obtain the first and last of these dates:

```
  f,l = a.minmax
  f #=> [#<Date: 2013-10-01 ((2456567j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  l #=>  #<Date: 2015-04-01 ((2457114j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Now pass `f` and `l` to `all_months_in_range` to create an array that contains a date object for the first day of each month between `f` and `l`.

```
  b = all_months_in_range(f,l) 
    #=> [#<Date: 2013-10-01 ((2456567j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2013-11-01 ((2456598j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    ...
    #    #<Date: 2015-04-01 ((2457114j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 

  b.size #=> 19
```

I will skip an explanation of this helper method, as it is quite straightforward.

Compute that difference between arrays `b` and `a` to obtain the missing beginning-of-month dates:

```
  c = b-a
    #=> [#<Date: 2013-12-01 ((2456628j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2014-05-01 ((2456779j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2014-07-01 ((2456840j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2014-08-01 ((2456871j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
    #    #<Date: 2015-02-01 ((2457055j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

Lastly, convert these dates to the desired format:

```
 c.map { |d| d.strftime('%b %Y') } 
   #=> ["Dec 2013", "May 2014", "Jul 2014", "Aug 2014", "Feb 2015"]
```

Addendum: after reading @Sid's answer, I see I could have saved myself some trouble in my helper method by using `Date#next_month`:

```
def all_months_in_range(f,l)
  (12*(l.year-f.year)+l.month-f.month+1).times.map { |i| f.next_month(i) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very elegant, but it worked. I started with your original code, @SupremeA, and built off of that.

```
require 'date'

dates = ['Wed, 23 Oct 2013', 'Mon, 18 Nov 2013', 'Fri, 22 Nov 2013', 'Mon, 13 Jan 2014', 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014', 'Mon, 03 Feb 2014', 'Mon, 10 Feb 2014', 'Tue, 18 Feb 2014', 'Fri, 07 Mar 2014', 'Mon, 31 Mar 2014', 'Mon, 07 Apr 2014', 'Tue, 10 Jun 2014', 'Mon, 30 Jun 2014', 'Mon, 22 Sep 2014', 'Mon, 06 Oct 2014', 'Fri, 14 Nov 2014', 'Tue, 18 Nov 2014', 'Fri, 26 Dec 2014', 'Thu, 15 Jan 2015', 'Mon, 23 Mar 2015', 'Mon, 20 Apr 2015']

new_dates = []
dates.each { |d| new_dates.push(Date.parse(d).strftime('%B %Y')) }
sorted_dates = new_dates.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%B %Y') }.sort.uniq
missing_months = []
sorted_dates.each_cons(2) do |d1,d2| 
  d = d1
  while d.next_month != d2 
    missing_months.push(d.next_month.strftime('%B %Y')) 
    d = d >> 1
  end 
end
p missing_months

=> ["December 2013", "May 2014", "July 2014", "August 2014", "February 2015"]
```